# Chart JS Canvas resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, resize, chart.js

[image]

I am currently sizing my charts within the canvas.

```
<div>
<canvas
     id="OrdersFufilledChart"
     ref={this.OrdersFufilledChart}
     width={360}
     height={360}
     />
</div>
```

I am looking to extend the canvas out to fit the width of the div but keep the chart the same size. As seen in the image the canvas has been highlighted and I wish to extend this out. I have tried

`maintainAspectRatio: false`

but that messes up my bootstrap layout. Does anyone have any insight on how I can do this